# How to do Schema Migration Using Ollie?

Tags: android, orm

I'm currently using Ollie ORM in my android app.
And I want to do some schema migration.

If I look into [this](https://github.com/pardom/Ollie/issues/5), I conclude that I should I create a new class. I've created the migration class as below:

```
import ollie.Migration; 

public class MigrateToVersionTwo extends Migration {
    @Override
    public int getVersion() {
        return 2;
    }

   @Override
    public String[] getStatements() {
        return new String[]{
                "ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN test INTEGER;"
        };
    }
}
```

I've also change the database_version from 1 become 2.

But the there's nothing changed to the schema.. Am I missing something?

If you need more information, here's the AdapterHolderImpl.java class:

```
package ollie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import ollie.adapter.BooleanAdapter;
import ollie.adapter.CalendarAdapter;
import ollie.adapter.SqlDateAdapter;
import ollie.adapter.UtilDateAdapter;
import ollie.internal.AdapterHolder;
import ollie.internal.ModelAdapter;

public final class AdapterHolderImpl
    implements AdapterHolder {
    private static final List<Migration> MIGRATIONS = new ArrayList<Migration>();
    private static final Map<Class<? extends Model>, ModelAdapter> MODEL_ADAPTERS = new HashMap<Class<? extends Model>, ModelAdapter>();
    private static final Map<Class, TypeAdapter> TYPE_ADAPTERS = new HashMap<Class, TypeAdapter>();

    static {
        MODEL_ADAPTERS.put(com.me.model.SafeZoneVO.class, new ollie.SafeZoneVO$$ModelAdapter());
        MODEL_ADAPTERS.put(com.me.model.EventVO.class, new ollie.EventVO$$ModelAdapter());
        MODEL_ADAPTERS.put(com.me.model.ContactVO.class, new ollie.ContactVO$$ModelAdapter());
        MODEL_ADAPTERS.put(com.me.model.User.class, new ollie.User$$ModelAdapter());
        MODEL_ADAPTERS.put(com.me.model.Place.class, new ollie.Place$$ModelAdapter());

        TYPE_ADAPTERS.put(java.util.Calendar.class, new CalendarAdapter());
        TYPE_ADAPTERS.put(java.util.Date.class, new UtilDateAdapter());
        TYPE_ADAPTERS.put(java.lang.Boolean.class, new BooleanAdapter());
        TYPE_ADAPTERS.put(java.sql.Date.class, new SqlDateAdapter());
    }

    public final List<? extends Migration> getMigrations() {
        return MIGRATIONS;
    }

    public final <T extends Model> ModelAdapter<T> getModelAdapter(Class<? extends Model> cls) {
        return MODEL_ADAPTERS.get(cls);
    }

    public final List<? extends ModelAdapter> getModelAdapters() {
        return new ArrayList(MODEL_ADAPTERS.values());
    }

    public final <D, S> TypeAdapter<D, S> getTypeAdapter(Class<D> cls) {
        return TYPE_ADAPTERS.get(cls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what is generated for `AdapterHolderImpl.java`?

Comment: @MichaelPardo I've added the AdapterHolderImpl.java code

Comment: What version are you using? There used to be a bug which prevented migrations from being created, which is what I'm seeing here.

Comment: @MichaelPardo I'm using version 0.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I have to use the latest version (currently `0.3.2-SNAPSHOT`).

So, I changed the build gradle to:

```
apt 'com.michaelpardo:ollie-compiler:0.3.2-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.michaelpardo:ollie:0.3.2-SNAPSHOT'
```

And added repositories for the snapshot version:

```
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"}
```